# Sending Emails from PHP

Tags: php

I am sending emails from a php form, it delivers the messages fine however since i added message priority the form delivers the message to and from the same email address.

Example:

```
$email = $row['SUBSCRIPTIONS_EMAIL_FROM']; --> subscriptions@example.com

$emailto = $row['SUBSCRIPTIONS_EMAIL_TO']; --> me@example.com

$subject = $row['SUBSCRIPTIONS_1ST_NOTICE_SUBJECT'];

$headers = "From: $email";

$send = mail($emailto, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

It delivers the email to and from fine with the given email addresses from SQL

But since I add additional headers for message priority:

```
$email = $row['SUBSCRIPTIONS_EMAIL_FROM']; --> subscriptions@example.com

$emailto = $row['SUBSCRIPTIONS_EMAIL_TO']; --> me@example.com

$subject = $row['SUBSCRIPTIONS_1ST_NOTICE_SUBJECT'];

$headers = "From: $email";

$headers = "X-Priority: 1 (Highest)\n"; 

$headers = "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n"; 

$headers = "Importance: High\n";

$send = mail($emailto, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

It delivers emails to and from the `$emailto:` email address.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: glad that you are receiving mails... so what is the question ?

Comment: how can I get it to show to and from email address properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things meet my eye first:

1. You overwrite your $headers multiple times:
2. You should use carriage return and new lines to separate the line "\r\n".

Instead of this:

```
$headers = "From: $email";
$headers = "X-Priority: 1 (Highest)\n"; 
$headers = "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n"; 
$headers = "Importance: High\n";
```

Try concatenating and use line proper separators:

```
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 1 (Highest)\r\n"; 
$headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Importance: High\r\n";
```

Comment: Perfect!!!! this works great. did not realize I was making such a small mistake. Thank you sooo much Leif